# MVC3 global predicate filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, filter, predicate

I am building an admin console and all controllers depend on a dropdown selection for customer.

I would like to move this customer selection to the layout and persist it across all controllers so that you do not need to select it everywhere.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move the dropdown to your _layout.cshtml.
2. Create a BaseView that all views will inherit from and give it a property to store the Customers & Current Customer.
3. Create a BaseController method that will fill in a BaseView instance.
4. Store the currently selected customer on your session.
5. Create a Global Filter and have it check all views to see if they inherit BaseView.  If they do it can convert them to a BaseView and then fill in the properties.
6. Write some code in the _layout that can use the View to fill in the dropdown.  I'm a bit fuzzy here since my coworker actually did this part when we did something similar.
7. When the user changes the dropdown value you can use JSON to call an action method that will update the current customer in session.

Comment: Thanks. I will implement this tomorrow and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing HTML helper. You assume that all the birds can fly, but say one day you have another exceptional scenario and you no longer need this dropdown box. Alternatively include it in a partial view and render that view where you need it - it's only one extra line of code.

E.g.

```
@section main_content{

   @{ Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialViewContainingDropDownBox"); }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but would this not require binding the dropdown value in every action?

Comment: I would include the SelectList in the viewbag when needed.